# Export several DataTable objects to different .csv files

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, export

I would like to export different DataTable objects into different .csv files using a foreach loop and the method "WriteDataTable". The size of the Datatable objects is very small (just 15 columns and 2 rows).

This is the foreach loop:

```
foreach (var dt in DataTableList)
{
    // Name of the file
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    // Call method
    WriteDataTable(fileName, dt);
}
```

This is the method:

```
public void WriteDataTable(string fileName, DataTable dt)
{  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                                .Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
    }

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());            
}
```

The program runs properly but only some of the DataTable objects are really exported. It looks like the previous DataTable object is still being exported when the new DataTable object comes. If I pause the process using "Thread.Sleep (500)" all objects are exported:

```
foreach (var dt in DataTableList)
{
    // Name of the file
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    // Call method
    WriteDataTable(fileName, dt);

    // Pause the process
    Thread.Sleep (500);
}
```

Any suggestion to export all the DataTable objects without slowing down the process?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another thread creating/modifying the DataTableList or the items in it while you're saving them?  DataSet, DataTable and related classes are not thread-safe.  Maybe you can elaborate on what you mean by "It looks like the previous DataTable object is still being exported when the new DataTable object comes."?

Comment: I found the problem. Since I use "DateTime.Now" (until seconds) as file names, when I export two files within the same second the first export file is overwrited by the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Since I use "DateTime.Now" (until seconds) as file names, when I export two files within the same second the first export file is overwrited by the second one.